# How to get rid of GRUB teminal (dual boot)?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, boot-repair, grub-efi

I have tried to solve this using boot-repair but it did nothing. I can still stop the boot sequence and get into choosing the Windows10/Ubuntu. But doing a regular startup i always get stuck in grub-terminal. And trying to do something there for every partitino `ls <disk partition>` i would get `unknown filesystem`
[report before boot-repair](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/HMtw5zfSPS)
**All i want to is to get back the grub menu back** [grub menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXApq.jpg)

---

Somehow i still got the grub terminal and the question still remains. I did the installation following your instruction link. And i did it like that the first time around when i encountered grub terminal for the first time. That is the reason why i tried with two EFIs because for two disks that was recommended and it worked properly (with normal grub MENU) for a short period of time. When with two EFIs it was fine until actually me turning on fast boot/changing grub timeout. Also zried boot-repair. Nope. Before: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Qx7ffWggtJ/
After: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/MyYtzrYfQj/

---

I had it for a brief moment normal when having 2 EFIs. I think i got myself out of grub terminal with pressing ESC, ESC+Shift or something like that. But with turning fast boot again everything went wrong.

Comment: What brand/model system? Boot-Repair suggested turning off UEFI Secure Boot, have you tried that? When you say interrupt boot, are you using UEFI boot menu?

Comment: HP-ENVY-x360-15-bp1xx, turned off Secure Boot and fast boot

Comment: This is what it looks like: _http://www.deviantpics.com/image/klY_
_http://www.deviantpics.com/image/klG_

Comment: I am not sure what are you trying to do. Are you trying to boot straight into Windows, and avoid grub2? At least that's what your headline suggests.

Comment: I  want to boot to the grub menu not to the grub terminal.

Comment: Ah, I see. You have a broken GRUB2, or corrupted or non-existent `grub.cfg` file. You will need to boot up Ubuntu in a live usb/dvd and install, then run [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

Comment: @PaulBenson 
As i stated boot-repair does not solve the problem. Any other ideas?

Comment: There seems to be a conflict within your ESP|. According to the pastebin you have 2 boot partitions, `/dev/nvme0n1p1` and `/dev/sda2`, whereas there should just be the latter, which is shared between Windows and Ubuntu.  Furthermore in your fstab file `/dev/nvme0n1p1` is the entry shown instead of `/dev/sda2`. I don't know why you are having an issue with boot-repair but that would have sorted this all out. I've used it myself on occasion and never had an issue with it.

Comment: I have Ubuntu and WIn on separate hdds. So i made an efi partition for each. Is there an alternate solution to boot-repair?(it doesn't seem to work for me)?

Comment: @PaulBenson Here is the report after running boot-repair http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/4jbnGW3R45/

Comment: I've deleted it from GParted menu when reinstalling Ubuntu. When enabling SecureBoot it went straight to Windows. I have my win disk image on an external drive. My HP model is bp102ng.

Comment: Is Ubuntu still shown as first drive in BIOS order? What happens if you disable Secure Boot again?

Comment: In BIOS I can't set the boot priority both are under the same option in the ordering. That's how it with this HP.

Comment: And oh btw nothing happens with or without secure boot it manages after turning it off to boot just once without the grib terminal.

Answer (score 0):

This is where I think you have gone adrift. As explained earlier your pastebin shows 2 different boot partitions for Ubuntu, which are obviously in conflict. Windows 10 already has its own 100MB boot partition (shown as Efi System partition), when it was installed. You can see this in W10 when you run command `diskmgmt.msc` In fact you don't even need to make any boot partition as when you install Ubuntu it should automatically make its own EFI `/boot` partition, where GRUB should configure itself to carry the identical files in the Windows boot partition. Without boot-repair it could take a few hours to and fro trying different things to get this to work with the risk you could screw up booting into Windows. It's not worth the time and trouble. I recommend you just re-install Ubuntu.

First of all check that you can still boot into W10 without issue. When there, run `diskmgmt.msc` and delete all partitions of **Ubuntu** only. You should be back to unallocated space for it. Then boot from your live Ubuntu USB to install it. When asked to choose 'installation type', choose option *something else*. Just follow instructions [here](https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/), starting from step 4 which are very well explained. When you've done that make sure your BIOS/UEFI is set to boot from Ubuntu as first disk. Let us know how you get on.

Comment: I can't delete the other redundant EFI partition that i made whilst installing ubuntu last time. How can I ho about deleting it?

Comment: If you boot into Windows and run Disk Management (`diskmgmt.msc`). You'll see the Windows partitions - (NTFS format) and Microsoft Reserved Partition (FAT32), usually 500MB size. Leave those alone. W10 cannot id Ubuntu partition formats so their formats are not shown.Those volumes should  be deleted. I'm not sure what you mean by 'unable to delete *redundant* efi partition' in Disk Management'. Can you put up an image of what you are seeing?

Comment: I have Win on hdd1 and Lnx on hdd2. I am not talking about touching anything from hdd1. I have an efi partition on hdd1(main one) and hdd2. The thing is when i get into win diskmgmt on hdd1 i can't delete the efi partition that i made on hdd2 when i was installing ubuntu. Is that ok? Can I delete it while reinstalling Ubuntu?

Comment: You keep the EFI on hdd1. That should be showing as Windows System Reserved Partition, and has no drive letter. You lose the EFI on hdd2 as well as the other partitions on that drive. BUT...You also have an NTFS Windows data partition on hdd2 of 723CB, which I hope you've backed up, as you don't want to delete that by accident. At least that's what your pastebin is saying. Please confirm.

Comment: Somehow i still got the grub terminal and the question still remains. I did the installation following your instruction link. And i did it like that the first time around when i encountered grub terminal for the first time. That is the reason why i tried with two EFIs because for two disks that was recommended and it worked properly (with normal grub MENU) for a short period of time. When with two EFIs it was fine until actually me turning on fast boot/changing grub timeout.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I've noticed at the end of the boot-repair, it said... *boot repair was successful* ...and... *Please do not forget to make your BIOS boot on nvme0n1p1/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi file*.

Two things. shimx64.efi is used when Secure Boot is enabled. Normally that would be disabled and then grub64.efi is the standard efi to boot with. So I would go into BIOS and enable SB just to start with and see what happens. By the way HP machines enable SB by default. I think you may have one of those. You can always disable SB again afterwards. FastBoot should be disabled.

Secondly, although most of the printout looks OK, the Ubuntu boot partition is still pointing to the Windows boot and not its own.Did you delete that efi partition on your Ubuntu drive before you reinstalled as you originally said you couldn't? It is still showing the same UUID so I guess you left it on. There are 2 ways of deleting it, but not from disk management. Is your data backed up?

Answer (score 0):

I think we're getting closer to the real issue. You should see 2 boot options in your BIOS for a hdd, one for Windows Boot Manager, and the other for Ubuntu. That is shown in my BIOS (a Dell). Using either as 1st boot, the latter takes me to grub where I also have a Windows option. The Windows Boot Manager BIOS option boots me straight into Windows - no grub menu, but then I don't use Secure Boot.

Not owning an HP or being familiar with their BIOS, I'm not sure I can take this much further. But you can have a look at [this](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c04784866) which has a whole section on HP BIOS and Secure Boot. My final suggestion is boot into Live ubuntu again (secure boot enabled) and run command `sudo update-grub`. If that doesn't help, I think this may be a question for the HP forum rather than Ubuntu. If you imaged your Windows **before** you did any Ubuntu installation, there may still be a way round this, otherwise good luck.

Comment: I had a Dell before and dual booted flawlessly, I know exactly what you are talking about. This is the HP case and as u can see youb can't choose. http://www.deviantpics.com/image/krP
http://www.deviantpics.com/image/krA It just lets you see the options.

Comment: `sudo update-grub` did nothing. Btw this is what boot-repair does to my system  http://www.deviantpics.com/image/kr5. P.S. see my edited post

Comment: Hi. Can you repost as a new question, as it's getting pretty congested on this page.  I have a couple of new ideas to try, but you'll need a [Windows 10 Recovery disk or USB](https://www.pcworld.com/article/3140449/windows/everything-you-need-to-know-about-windows-10-recovery-drives.html) if you haven't already made one, just in case anything goes wrong with your Windows boot-up. I'll get back to you within 2-3 hours when if/ you confirm you want to continue..

Comment: please do i agree

Comment: OK. Without reinstalling W10 I'm going to suggest first removing all traces of Ubuntu from your laptop starting with W10. I expect your boot folders include Ubuntu efi files which need to be deleted. In case anything goes wrong and you can't boot Windows, 1) Do you have your W10 image to hand and was it made before installing Ubuntu? b) How did you make it - ie with a 3rd party tool or from using  W10 image backup? 3) Do you have a Windows Recovery disk/USB I suggested you make in my previous post? 4) Do you know how to boot into the W10 Administrator account?

Comment: Isn't there a way of deleting boot entries without reinstalling windows? I have no recovery usb  I stored the sys image on an external HDD. I do not have the luxury to tamper with win10 and no time to pursue this anymore. I am very thankful for your effort and time but sadly we haven't managed to find a feasible solution (without breaking my setup up).  I will stick to boot interrupt because it still gets me where I want.